# Rails :: Capistrano :: sh: whenever: not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, whenever, whenever-capistrano

I am trying to deploy a project that uses whenever.

But getting:

```
sh: whenever: not found
rolling back
executing "rm -rf /var/www/rails_apps/portal/releases/20130627122943; true"

failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/rails_apps/portal/releases/20130627122943 && whenever --update-crontab iconnect_portal --set environment=production --roles db'" on ...
```

#### Gemfile

```
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

#### deploy.rb

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
require "whenever/capistrano"
require "delayed/recipes"
........
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to use "bundle exec" here.

```
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

This is mentioned in the official documentation :)
https://github.com/javan/whenever

Answer (score 0):

You will have to require 'whenever' explicitly because of your `:required => false` in the Gemfile. The bundler will not require it automatically when you have `:required =>  false`.